# using select stdin for non blocking input python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, stdin

I want to create a process that has 3 sub processes, 2 to handle websockets and one to get input from terminal to pass to the other two sockets.

```py
import sys
import time
import select
import asyncio

import threading

import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process


def managment_api():
    poller = select.poll()
    poller.register(sys.stdin, select.POLLIN)


    started = True
    count   = 0

    while started:
        print("management api [{:^6}]".format(count))

        while sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
            _line = sys.stdin.readline()
            if _line:
                line = _line.strip().lower()
                if(line == "exit" or line == "quit"):
                    started = False
                    print("got exit message [{}]".format(started))
                else:
                  pass

        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)

def process_main(loop):
    print("process_main BEGIN")
    loop.run_in_executor(None, managment_api())
    print("process_main ENG  ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #this doesn't work
    main = Process(target=managment_api, args=())
    main.name = "management api"
    main.start()
    main.join()
    """

    #asyncio.run(managment_api()) #need to add async to management_api
```

When I make management_api an async function and call asyncio.run(management_api); I can get input.

If I try to run the same code without async in a separate process it, I get stuck in the `while sys.stdin in selec...` section of the code. I've tried with threads but that doesn't work either.

How can I run this code from a separate process, to get the input in another process?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by first, using `fn = sys.stdin.fileno()` to get the main process file descriptor, passing that as an argument to the subprocess. Then using `sys.stdin = os.fdopen(fn)`

```py
import sys
import time
import select
import asyncio

import threading

import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process


def managment_api(fn):
    sys.stdin = os.fdopen(fn)

    poller = select.poll()
    poller.register(sys.stdin, select.POLLIN)


    started = True
    count   = 0

    while started:
        print("management api [{:^6}]".format(count))

        while sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
            _line = sys.stdin.readline()
            if _line:
                line = _line.strip().lower()
                if(line == "exit" or line == "quit"):
                    started = False
                    print("got exit message [{}]".format(started))
                else:
                  pass

        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)

def process_main(loop):
    print("process_main BEGIN")
    loop.run_in_executor(None, managment_api())
    print("process_main ENG  ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fn = sys.stdin.fileno()
    main = Process(target=managment_api, args=(fn, ))
    main.name = "management api"
    main.start()
    main.join()
    """

    #asyncio.run(managment_api()) #need to add async to management_api
```